# tryCatch r in raster::calc

Tags: r, error-handling, try-catch, r-raster

I'm wanting to write a function that will (hopefully) work in the raster calculator in the `raster` package. What I'm trying to do is regress each cell value against a vector of Time. There are multiple examples of this, but what I would like to do is for the method to try 1 type of regression (gls, controlling for AR1 residual errors), but if for some reason that regression throws an error (perhaps there is no AR1 structure in the residuals) then to revert back to simple OLS regression.

I've written two functions for the regression. One for `gls`:

```
# function for calculating the trend, variability, SNR, and residuals for each pixel
## this function will control for AR1 structure in the residuals
funTrAR1 <- function(x, ...) {if (sum(is.na(x)) >= 1) { NA } else {
  mod <- nlme::gls(x ~ Year, na = na.omit, method = "REML", verbose = TRUE,
                   correlation = corAR1(form = ~ Year, fixed = FALSE),
                   control = glsControl(tolerance = 1e-3, msTol = 1e-3, opt = c("nlminb", "optim"),
                                        singular.ok = TRUE, maxIter = 1000, msMaxIter = 1000))
  slope <- mod$coefficients[2]
  names(slope) <- "Trend"
  var <- sd(mod$residuals)
  names(var) <- "Variability"
  snr <- slope/var
  names(snr) <- "SNR"
  residuals <- c(stats::quantile(
    mod$residuals, probs = seq(0,1,0.25), 
    na.rm = TRUE, names = TRUE, type = 8), 
    base::mean(mod$residuals, na.rm = TRUE))
  names(residuals) <- c("P0", "P25", "P50", "P75", "P100", "AvgResid")
  return(c(slope, var, snr, residuals))}
}
```

and for `OLS`:

```
# function for calculating the trend, variability, SNR, and residuals for each pixel
## this function performs simple OLS
funTrOLS <- function(x, ...) {if (sum(is.na(x)) >= 1) { NA } else {
  mod <- lm(x ~ Year, na.action = na.omit)
  slope <- mod$coefficients[2]
  names(slope) <- "TrendOLS"
  var <- sd(mod$residuals)
  names(var) <- "VariabilityOLS"
  snr <- slope/var
  names(snr) <- "SNROLS"
  residuals <- c(stats::quantile(
    mod$residuals, probs = seq(0,1,0.25), 
    na.rm = TRUE, names = TRUE, type = 8), 
    base::mean(mod$residuals, na.rm = TRUE))
  names(residuals) <- c("P0", "P25", "P50", "P75", "P100", "AvgResid")
  return(c(slope, var, snr, residuals))}
}
```

I'm trying to wrap these in a tryCatch expression which can be passed to `raster::calc`

```
xReg <- tryCatch(
  {
    funTrAR1  
  },
  error = function(e) {
    ## this should create a text file if a model throws an error
    sink(paste0(inDir, "/Outputs/localOLSErrors.txt"), append = TRUE)
    cat(paste0("Used OLS regression (grid-cell) for model: ", m, ". Scenario: ", t, ". Variable: ", v, ". Realisation/Ensemble: ", r, ". \n"))
    sink()
    ## run the second regression function
    funTrOLS
  }
)
```

This function is then passed to `raster::calc` like so

```
cellResults <- calc(rasterStack, fun = xReg)
```

Which if everything works will produce a raster stack of the output variables that looks similar to this

[image: calc output]

However, for some of my datasets the loop that I'm running all of this in stops and I receive the following error:

```
 Error in nlme::gls(x ~ Year, na = na.omit, method = "REML", verbose = TRUE,  : 
  false convergence (8)
```

Which is directly from `nlme::gls` and what I was hoping to avoid. I've never used `tryCatch` before (this might be very obvious), but does anyone know how to get the `tryCatch()` to move to the second regression function if the first (AR1) regression fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way to code this, perhaps that helps:

```
xReg <- function(x, ...) {
    r <- try(funTrAR1(x, ...), silent=TRUE)
    # if (class(r) == 'try-error') { 
    if (!is.numeric(r)) {  # perhaps a faster test than the one above
        r <- c(funTrOLS(x, ...), 2)
    } else {
        r <- c(r, 1)
    }
    r
}
```

I add a layer that shows which model was used for each cell.

You can also do

```
xReg <- function(x, ...) {
    r <- funTrOLS(x, ...)
    try( r <- funTrAR1(x, ...), silent=TRUE)
    r
}
```

Or use calc twice and use `cover` after that

```
xReg1 <- function(x, ...) {
    r <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA)
    try( r <- funTrAR1(x, ...), silent=TRUE)
    r
}
xReg2 <- function(x, ...) {
    funTrOLS(x, ...)
}

a <- calc(rasterStack, xReg1)
b <- calc(rasterStack, xReg2)
d <- cover(a, b)
```

And `a` will show you where xReg1 failed.

Answer (score 0):

After doing a bit more reading, and also looking at @RobertH answer, I wrote a bit of (very) ugly code that checks if GLS will fail and if it does, performs OLS instead. I'm positive that there is a nicer way to do this, but it works and maintains raster layer names as they were defined in my functions, it also exports any errors to a txt file.

```
for (i in 1) {
            j <- tempCentredRas
            cat(paste("Checking to see if gls(AR1) will work for model", m, r,"cell based calculations\n", sep = " "))
            ### This check is particularly annoying as it has to do this for every grid-cell
            ### it therefore has to perform GLS/OLS on every grid cell twice
            ### First to check if it (GLS) will fail, and then again if it does fail (use OLS) or doesn't (use GLS)
            possibleLocalError <- tryCatch(
              raster::calc(j, fun = funTrAR1),
              error = function(err) 
                err
            )
            if (inherits(possibleLocalError, "error")) {
              cat(paste("GLS regression failed for model", m, r, "using OLS instead for cell based results.","\n", sep = " "))
              cellResults <- raster::calc(j, fun = funTrOLS)
            } else {
              cellResults <- raster::calc(j, fun = funTrAR1)
            }
          }
```